# Polymer Check for Insertion Points

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm starting to learn Polymer 1.0 and I couldn't figure out how to programatically search for insertion points. I realize I could wrap a `<div>` around the `<content>` tag and check if that `<div>` has children or not, but that requires rendering a `<div>` for every element, which seems wasteful. Is there a way, with JavaScript, to check if any insertion points have been loaded? Ideally, I'd have a function `thereAreInsertionPoints` which would determine whether or not the `<p>` tag would render. My Polymer code looks like this:

```
  <template>
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <p>{{body}}</p>
      <content id="content"></content>
      <p if="{{thereAreInsertionPoints()}}">There are insertion points!</p>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "post-content",
      properties: {
        title: String,
        body: String
      },
      thereAreInsertionPoints: function(){
        //determine whether or not we have insertion points
      }
    });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various [Polymer APIs for working with the DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api) including **Content APIs**.

> Content APIs:
>
> - Polymer.dom(contentElement).getDistributedNodes()
> - Polymer.dom(node).getDestinationInsertionPoints()

These APIs can be used in various ways to check for distributed nodes and insertion points.  I have created a working implementation that shows the `post-content` element with additional methods to check for distributed nodes and destination insertion points.

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import"
      href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="post-content">
 <template>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>{{body}}</p>
  <content></content>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{destinationInsertionPointsExist()}}">
   <p>Destination insertion point(s) exist.</p>
  </template>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{distributedNodesExist()}}">
   <p>Distributed node(s) exist.</p>
  </template>
 </template>
 <script>
  Polymer({
   is: "post-content",
   properties: {
    title: String,
    body: String
   },
   destinationInsertionPointsExist: function () {
    var distributedNodes = Polymer.dom(this).childNodes;

    var countDestinationInsertionPoints = 0;
    distributedNodes.forEach(function (distributedNode) {
     var distributedNodeHasDestinationInsertionPoints = Polymer.dom(distributedNode).getDestinationInsertionPoints().length > 0 ? true : false;

     if (distributedNodeHasDestinationInsertionPoints) {
      countDestinationInsertionPoints++;
     }
    });

    return countDestinationInsertionPoints > 0 ? true : false;
   },
   distributedNodesExist: function () {
    var contentNodes = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("content");

    var countDistributedNodes = 0;
    contentNodes.forEach(function(contentNode) {
     var contentNodehasDistributedNodes = Polymer.dom(contentNode).getDistributedNodes().length > 0 ? true : false;

     if (contentNodehasDistributedNodes) {
      countDistributedNodes++;
     }
    });

    return countDistributedNodes > 0 ? true : false;
   }
  });
 </script>
</dom-module>

<post-content title="This is the title" body="This is the body">
 <p>This is distributed content</p>
</post-content>
```

A few notes about the code:

- I made a lot of the variable names and ternary checks very verbose for clarity in this answer.  Changes could be made to simplify the code.

  For example:

  `var distributedNodeHasDestinationInsertionPoints = Polymer.dom(distributedNode).getDestinationInsertionPoints().length > 0 ? true : false;`

  could become something like

  `var hasInsertionPoints = Polymer.dom(distributedNode).getDestinationInsertionPoints().length`
- Use the new (Polymer 1.0) `dom-if` conditional template.

  `<p if="{{thereAreInsertionPoints()}}">There are insertion points!</p>`

  becomes

```html
<template is="dom-if" if="{{destinationInsertionPointsExist()}}">
    <p>Destination insertion point(s) exist.</p>
</template>
```

- I would recommend stepping through the `destinationInsertionPointsExist` and `distributedNodesExist` methods to insure that you fully understand what is actually being checked.  You may need to modify these methods to suit your particular needs and requirements.

  - For example, even if you have a single space between the `post-content` element start and end tag both of these methods will return true.

    `<post-content title="This is the title" body="This is the body"> </post-content>`

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. I was trying something like you were saying to no avail, but I think the problem, like you mentioned, was that there was whitespace inbetween the `<post-content>` tags. Thanks again!